'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' -Error with Twitch API
I tried to fetch some data with the twitch.tv API on a little JavaScript project.
Here is the fetch request:
fetch("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/chat/emotes/global", {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Bearer XXX",
                    ClientId: "MY_ID"
}}) 

I tried to fetch the data on an vercel site and got this error

Access to fetch at 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/chat/emotes/global' from origin "MY-WEBSITE'' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

None of the solutions I tried worked and I thought its a vercel only error so it uploaded the code on my own website, but still the same error
I have no idea what is wrong
I found this guide but it wasn't helpful
Also found this site which also didn't work

are you sure you are using the correct headers?

I ask because some API's (like the one you are using) don't bother sending CORS headers if you don't at least send the correct header names - regardless if the header values are valid. Read the documentation that will tell you what headers you need to send in the request

Good call by Jaromanda X: the documented header name is not ClientID, but Client-Id. Compare the output of curl -v -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: https://example.com" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,clientid" 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/chat/emotes/global' and curl -v -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: https://example.com" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,client-id" 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/chat/emotes/global'.

fetch("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/chat/emotes/global", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer XXX',
        'Client-Id': 'MY_ID',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    mode: 'cors'  // Include this to handle CORS
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));

try this

"try this" Why? Please add an explanation of what you've done differently and why.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I added this sorry: mode: 'cors'
